# PHP spiking cpu usage

Tags: php, caching, cpu, cpu-usage, apc

I was testing my site with Jmeter to see how hundred threads would affect site performance and tested it with apache and mod_php and nginx with fastcgi. I noticed that the bottlebeck was always cpu in both apache and nginx. when I was looking at spu usage in nginx setup I could see that php cgi processes were taking all cpu.

What can I do to decrease php cpu usage?

Comment: What are the settings of your GC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason PHP is taking up more resources than your web servers is that PHP is doing a lot more work, and does so in an intepreted language (Apache and Nginx is both compiled into CPU instructions).

The first step is to implement an opcode cache (I recommend APC since it's easily installed and maintained by the PHP people). This will cache a "compiled" version of your scripts which will remove a big bit of the script execution.

The only other way to decrease CPU usage is to make your code more effective. Try to identify bottlenecks (large arrays and other data structures may be the first to check out) and find ways to make those parts of the code perform better.

Comment: +1 Note thought that Emil means "compiled" not in the sense of "compiled to machine code" but in the sense of "compiled to opcodes" (those can be compared to Java's bytecode)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do have ACP extension installed. Do I need to do anyhting to configure it, or is just installing and enabling it enough?

Comment: Just enabling it should be enough, but please read the configuration part of the manual anyway since there are some options which impact the cache performance (especially the size of the cache and filesystem stat() calls).